# Running a Stack Overflow query from Python

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm working on improving my answer to [a question on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119575/how-can-i-view-all-my-unaccepted-questions-across-se/222562#222562). I want to run a search on some Stack Exchange site and detect whether I got any results. For example, I might run [this query](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+hasaccepted%3Ano+answers%3A1+lastactive%3A2013-12-24..2014-02-22+). When I run the query through my browser, I don't see the string "Your search returned no matches" anywhere in the html I get. But when I run this Python code:

```
"Your search returned no matches" in urllib2.urlopen("https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+hasaccepted%3Ano+answers%3A1+lastactive%3A2013-12-24..2014-02-22+").read()
```

I get `True`, and in fact the string contains a page that is clearly different from the one I get in my browser. How can I run the search in a way that gets me the same result I get when running the query in the normal, human way (from a browser)?

UPDATE: here's the same thing done with `requests`, as suggested by @ThiefMaster♦. Unfortunately it gets the same result.

```
"Your search returned no matches" in requests.get("https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+hasaccepted%3Ano+answers%3A1+lastactive%3A2013-12-24..2014-02-22").text
```

---

I used FireBug to view the header of the GET that runs when I run the search from my browser. Here it is:

```
GET /search?q=user%3A128043+hasaccepted%3Ano+answers%3A1+lastactive%3A2013-12-24..2014-02-22 HTTP/1.1
Host: math.stackexchange.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A128043+hasaccepted%3Ano+answers%3A1+lastactive%3A2013-12-24..2014-02-22
Cookie: __qca=P0-1687127815-1387065859894; __utma=27693923.779260871.1387065860.1393095534.1393101885.19; __utmz=27693923.1393095534.18.10.utmcsr=stackoverflow.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/users/2829764/kuzzooroo; _ga=GA1.2.779260871.1387065860; mathuser=t=WM42SFDA5Uqr&s=OsFGcrXrl06g; sgt=id=bedc99bd-5dc9-42c7-85db-73cc80c4cc15; __utmc=27693923
Connection: keep-alive
```

Running requests.get with various pieces of this header didn't work for me, though I didn't try everything, and there are lots of possibilities.

Comment: please... use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/) instead of urllib :)

Answer (score 0):

Some sites create different results depending on which client connects to them. I do not know whether this is the case with stackoverflow. But I recognied it with wikis.

Here is what I do to pretend I am an Opera browser:

```
def openAsOpera(url):
    u = urllib.URLopener()
    u.addheaders = []
    u.addheader('User-Agent', 'Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; U; de) Presto/2.10.289 Version/12.01')
    u.addheader('Accept-Language', 'de-DE,de;q=0.9,en;q=0.8')
    u.addheader('Accept', 'text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, image/webp, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1')
    f = u.open(url)
    content = f.read()
    f.close()
    return content
```

Surely you can adapt this to pretend the client is Firefox.

Comment: Thanks for this pointer. Unfortunately it didn't work me; same result. I hope I didn't imply that I know the issue to be related to what browser I'm using. I don't know what the issue is.